# WinForms Designer - Adding control to tabPage

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have one tabControl with 4 tabPages. I added appropriated controls in the first 3 tabPages without any problems, but when I try to add(drag and drop from the toolbox) an textBox to tabPage4(active, highlighted element) it goes to tabPage1 instead.

Is this just some strange designer bug or am I missing some option ?

Comment: try to delete tab4 and re-insert.

Comment: I just tried, with the same behaviour described above

Comment: sounds weird. when you doubleclick page4, does it generate its click event? sounds like there is something wrong with either the tab or vs. restarting vs is cheap, shuffling the tabpages, too; recreating the whole tab would be the next idea; or adding at least one control manually in the form.designer.cs..

Comment: double clicking creates the right handler. strangly, I can move the the controls on the right side of my tabPage, but when I move it to the left side (roughly at crossing the center) it vanishes to tabPage1

Comment: Ah, so you have controls on page4? Any containers among them?

Comment: No, I added them (and found out ) after my question here. ANother insight, I can add *Powershapes* (rectangle, oval) anywhere on tab4. but native winform controls are all misbehaving

Comment: If all else fails, go into the designer code and manually add the TextBox control in there.

Answer (score 0):

That's weird I couldn't reproduce the same behaviour, is Visual Studio SP1 already installed?

Answer (score 0):

No solution, but I tried the test version of visual studio 2013 and here it works fine. Made the changes in 2013, and then switched back to 2010.

2013 has some weird issues with the visualbasic.powerpack btw..